# Oracle 11g "INSERT INTO SELECT" Misbehaving

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to do a very simple thing using the following sample query (can't post the actual query :( )

**INSERT INTO Students( id, roll_number, Student_name)
SELECT 1, 2, 'MyName' FROM DUAL;**

The ID Column has NOT NULL constraint set. When I execute this query I get the following error:
SQL Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."STUDENTS"."ID")
01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"

The ID column has datatype NUMBER.

Could anyone help what could be the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us a description the Students table? I see nothing wrong syntactically with your code.

Comment: the error is pretty much self-explanatory - your are trying to insert a null value into a non-null column. as it is advised, take a look at your query without the insert part and see what you are actually trying to insert - some of these values are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I am creating a habit of answering my own questions...

When I took a closer look into the table I found that there were two ID columns(of course with different names):

One column stores primary key for this table whereas,
other column stores the foreign key as a link to other table.

Thanks everyone for your responses, those made me wonder as to what wrong was I doing.

Thanks a Ton :)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is run the Select part separately, and look at the data that comes back.  i.e.

```
Select First_Field, Second_Field, 'Bob'
From MyTable
Where First_Field = NULL;
```

What that gives you.  You could also do:

```
Select count(*)
From MyTable
Where coalesce(First_Field,1) =1;
```

by the way, you said your field is a Numeric, however just FYI.  A '' inserted into a varchar2 field gets interpreted as a NULL.  Found that out the hard way

Comment: When I run the Select query seperately I get the following output:
1                      2                      MyName   
1 rows selected
Also, same are the results with coalesce